# Small rotary switch

Tags: switches, dip, rotary

I'm looking for a small rotary switch but don't know the terminology to find what I'm looking for. To be honest I'm not sure they make what I'm looking for. The closest I have found is this, a rotary dip switch.

[image]

But these encode the output. What I want is to have 8 input lines and 1 output line so the user and select one of the 8 input lines. I could do this with the dip switch, a decoder IC and a AND logic IC but I would *really* rather not need to have additional ICs.

I just need a small switch I can solder to a PCB and to let the user select one of 8 lines.

Answer (score 2):

You want a SP8T selector switch. For example, [this](http://www.ck-components.com/79723/rw_15may13.pdf/) one, but you should be able to find others now that you know what to call it.

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's the same one I found trough the mouser search tool. How can there be just *one* suitable part?

Comment: It's a rather rare requirement, but you can find some smallish through-hole rotary switches and at least one 10 position slide switch.

Comment: @jms  Here's a [3-position non-encoded switch](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/CS-4-13NTB/563-1036-2-ND/948347).

Comment: @NickAlexeev I was searching for 8pst specifically, and got surprised about the lack of variety.

Comment: @jms And, of course, if that one manufacturer decides to end production (and they will some day), you've got a real problem. Nothing else out there looks to be remotely as small.

Answer (score 1):

Just use a DIP switch with one side of all the DIP switches connected together into a common: as long as you can deal with use cases where more than one DIP switch is activated.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f5E2UN.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>